# Unable to add table option to syncfusion richtexteditor (REACT)

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, syncfusion

I'm having the same issue as in this [S.O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53407169/unable-to-add-table-option-to-syncfusion-richtexteditor). I also have this error in the console when i added Table to the RTE's toolbarSettings.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at n.getObject (webpack://%5Bname%5D/./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-richtexteditor/dist/ej2-richtexteditor.umd.min.js?:10)
    at r (webpack://%5Bname%5D/./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-richtexteditor/dist/ej2-richtexteditor.umd.min.js?:10)
    at n.getItems (webpack://%5Bname%5D/./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-richtexteditor/dist/ej2-richtexteditor.umd.min.js?:10)
    at n.getToolbarOptions (webpack://%5Bname%5D/./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-richtexteditor/dist/ej2-richtexteditor.umd.min.js?:10)
    at n.render (webpack://%5Bname%5D/./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-richtexteditor/dist/ej2-richtexteditor.umd.min.js?:10)
    at n.renderToolbar (webpack://%5Bname%5D/./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-richtexteditor/dist/ej2-richtexteditor.umd.min.js?:10)
    at e.notify (webpack://%5Bname%5D/./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-richtexteditor/node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/dist/ej2-base.umd.min.js?:1)
    at n.r.notify (webpack://%5Bname%5D/./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-richtexteditor/node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/dist/ej2-base.umd.min.js?:1)
    at n.i.render (webpack://%5Bname%5D/./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-richtexteditor/dist/ej2-richtexteditor.umd.min.js?:10)
    at n.render (webpack://%5Bname%5D/./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-react-richtexteditor/dist/ej2-react-richtexteditor.umd.min.js?:10)
```

I added the vendor files shown in that question answer to my app but i don't know how to make correctly the import for the js file

```
import './@syncfusionExtraVendors/@syncfusion-RTE/material.css';
import * from './@syncfusionExtraVendors/@syncfusion-RTE/ej2.min.js';
```

what i should import exactly from that js file and how to name it ?

Please, we would like to get a sample too on how to use the Table but for react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greetings from Syncfusion support.

We have validated the reported issue and we suspect you have configured “**Table**” as the item in **toolbarSettings.items** API. This is not a valid item in **toolbarSettings**, due to this reported issue occurs from your end.

We suggest you, configure “**CreateTable**” item, instead of “Table” in **toolbarSettings.items** API as mentioned below

```js
toolbarSettings = {
    items:  ['CreateTable']
}
```

**Note**: Rich Text Editor features are segregated into individual feature-wise modules. To use table tool, inject table module using the .

**Documentation about table**: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/rich-text-editor/table/

We have prepared sample for your reference, check the below link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rcdarc-ddncpt?file=index.js

**Query**:  1. what I should import exactly from that js file and how to name it? 
2. I added the vendor files shown in that question answer to my app but I don't know how to make correctly the import for the js file

`import './@syncfusionExtraVendors/@syncfusion-RTE/material.css';` - Style reference required, check the below-shared reference link

`import * from './@syncfusionExtraVendors/@syncfusion-RTE/ej2.min.js';`  - Not required

The above configuration is not required. Find the below documentation reference for getting started with RichTextEditor.

**Documentation**: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/rich-text-editor/getting-started/
**API**: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/rich-text-editor/